# Parser that controls is every { closed and matches the closest one

Tags: c, parsing, flexbox, bison

### My scanner is works fine but i couldn't find whats wrong with my parser

```
semi: "{" vallist "}"
    | "{" "}""
    ;
val: tSTR
   | tInt
   ;
vallist: vallist , val
       | val
       ;
```

Comment: Sounds like a contradiction? ... "works fine" .. "find whats wrong" ... so is it working or not? ... need more details to explain that difference.

Comment: double quotes (`"`) don't work the way you might think they do in bison -- you generally never want to use them in rules.  Use single quotes (`'`) for single character tokens.

Comment: @PaulT. like ı said my scanner returns correct tokens but my parser return syntax error examples like {1,2,3,4,5,{1,2}}

Comment: Perhaps you meant `","` in `vallist`. (Or `','`, which is different and more common.) But a plain `,`  is certainly wrong.

Comment: Anyway, a `vallist` evidently only contains `val`s and a nested `semi` isn't a val. So the grammar can't acceot that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems, some of which are probably just typos in your copy-paste (what you have above will be rejected by bison).

Your main problem is probably using `"` (double quotes) for your tokens, which for the most part doesn't do anything useful -- it creates a 'new' token that is not the same as the single character token your lexer probably returns.

Instead, you want to use `'` (single quotes):

```
semi: '{' vallist '}'
    | '{' '}'
    ;
val: tSTR
   | tInt
   | semi
   ;
vallist: vallist ',' val
       | val
       ;
```